# Optimal way to pass values from callable parameters in java

Tags: java, sql

I am looking for the best practice about passing values from a callable parameter object to  separate variables.

I am using an object of callable parameters to pass values to  variables. I am using numbers to represent the values of every parameter. Is there a more efficient way?

```java
//CREATES NEW OBJECT FOR COLLABLE PARAMETERS
CallableParameters params = new CallableParameters();
//PASS INPUT VALUES
params.addParamIn(ID(),Types.INTEGER); 
params.addParamIn(NUMBER(),Types.INTEGER); 


//RETURN OUTPUT VALUES
params.addParamIn(CITY(),Types.VARCHAR); 
params.addParamIn(YEAR(),Types.INTEGER); 

//EXECUTE THE COLLABLE STATEMENT TO RUN THE STORED PROCEDURE
CallableStatement.executeCallable(callableName, params, conn);
```

Then I try to pass the values to variables like this:

```java
String CITY = (Integer)params.getParams().get(3).getParamValue();
int YEAR=(String)params.getParams().get(4).getParamValue();
```

Is there a better way to call my variables instead of `get(3)`, like enum with names and like?

Comment: You can create an enum with an entry for each field, and the corresponding getter/setter methods. It's arguable whether that's more readable or elegant. I do like it.

Comment: Good question, but the answer will be opinion-based.

Comment: CallableParameters & executeCallable method are your API. NOT java built-in Jdbc API. The way you coded depends on the way your API were designed..... Java CallableStatement provides API to get output parameter by name...

Comment: @nicomp is it Just opinion based or are there factors like speed, reliability etc that have to do with java architecture (And i don't know of)?

Comment: @Loc is there a General guideline on witch solution to choose however?

Answer (score 1):

You can create am enum

```
enum ParameterSetter implements Consumer<CallableParameters> {
    ID {
        void accept(Callable Parameters setIn) {
            setIn.addParamIn(createId(), Types.INTEGER);
        } 
    }
    static String createId() {...} 
}
```

Then you can initialize your parameters like this

```
for (ParameterSetter setter : ParameterSetter.values()) {
    setter.accept(yourParameterObject);
}
```

Is a matter of taste I guess.

Comment: Besides human mistakes are there any other implications by using numbers instead of enum? Is it just a matter of taste?

Comment: I think there could be implications by using this syntax instead of getters & setters, since you could easily change a variable, without updating the numbers of your calls